# How to import a Python module that contains an exit() call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I'm trying to use `import_module()` to import a code file and run some unit tests. However the code file contains an `exit()` command, which is causing my tests to exit as well. Is there a way to import the module without the `exit()` command causing my test program to exit as well?

Other solutions I've seen put the import in a `try/except SystemExit` block, but that just avoids importing the module altogether. I need to actually import the module. So putting the import inside a `try` block does not solve the problem.

Comment: can you show the code.

Comment: you can use: `if __name__ == __main__: exit()` in other file.

Comment: I'm writing unit tests to test student code submissions, so we don't want to edit the student code

Comment: Care to clarify that *”that just avoids importing the module altogether”*?!

Comment: @deceze what happens if you `try` to import a module but catch a `SystemExit`, and the module does have an `exit()`? You go to the `except` clause and don't import the module

Comment: Ah, the `exit` is unconditionally right at the top level? In that case your student should probably simply fail the assignment…?!

Comment: Haha, while the `exit()` isn't top-level, importing the module does have the effect of executing the code which does make the call happen. In this particular case, it was a very unexpected solution to the problem but technically valid!

Comment: your approach is probably awkward - if they're explicitly designing modules, you could dynamically load them in the test potentially even [tokenizing it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) and verifying some structures, but is it more likely that they're self-contained programs which you could be `subprocess`-ing?

Comment: If I put the import in a subprocess how would it return a reference to the module before hitting the `exit()` call?